# Want to update user pic in nav drawer from device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want when someone cliks google login and his/her profile pic,email and name appears on drawer just like pic below, there should also be an option to update profile so that he/she can replace that pic from the device storage selected. And also when next time user login that device pic will remain intact and shouldnt be replaced by google id pic. [image]

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
import ...


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
    private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
    private TextView mName;
    private TextView mEmail;
    private String name;
    private String emailname;
    private Uri photoUrl;
    private ImageView mPic;
    private NavigationView mNavigationView;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    public String TAG = "Main Activity";
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        // Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance.
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        //myRef.setValue("Hello World");
        SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionPagerAdapter = new MainActivity.SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
        if(mAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null)
        {
            Log.d("AUTH",mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
            //user already signed in
        }else {
            startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build()))
                            .build(),
                    RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mName = (TextView) mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.username);
        mPic = (ImageView) mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mEmail = (TextView) mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.email);
        getCurrentUserInfo();

        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.nav_gallery:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"My Profile Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                    case R.id.nav_notifications:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Notifications Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                    case R.id.nav_liked_posts:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Liked Post",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                    case R.id.nav_slideshow:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Slideshow Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                    case R.id.log_out_button:
                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                                .signOut(MainActivity.this)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        Log.d("AUTH","USER LOGGED OUT");
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                });
                        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        return true;

                    default:
                        return true;
                }
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==RC_SIGN_IN){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                //user logged in
                Log.d("AUTH",mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                getCurrentUserInfo();
            }
            else {
                //user not authenticated
                Log.d("AUTH","NOT AUTHENTICATED");
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // TODO: Do something when the user submits the search query.
                Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextSubmit: Text Submitted");
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextChange: Text Changed");
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        /* if (id == R.id.action_search) {
            return true;
        } */

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    /*/For logout activity in navigation bar
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.log_out_button) {
        // Handle the action
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .signOut(this)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            Log.d("AUTH","USER LOGGED OUT");
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
         }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    */

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    Polls pollTab = new Polls();
                    return pollTab;
                case 1:
                    Facts factTab = new Facts();
                    return factTab;
                case 2:
                    News newsTab = new News();
                    return newsTab;

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    private void getCurrentUserInfo(){
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if(user!=null){

            for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()){
                String providerId = profile.getProviderId();
                String uid = profile.getUid();
                name = profile.getDisplayName();
                photoUrl = profile.getPhotoUrl();
                emailname = profile.getEmail();
                mName.setText(name);
                mEmail.setText(emailname);
                if(name!=null && emailname!=null) {
                    myRef.child("Users").child(name).child("Email").setValue(emailname);
                    myRef.child("Users").child(name).child("UserId").setValue(uid);
                    }
                if (photoUrl == null) {
                    Picasso.get()
                            .load(R.drawable.usericon)
                            .resize(6000,2000)
                            .centerInside()
                            .into(mPic);
                }else {
                    Picasso.get()
                            .load(photoUrl.toString())
                            .resize(6000, 2000)
                            .centerInside()
                            .into(mPic);
                }
                }
        }
        }
}
```

My activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Suggest me way to do this. I tried on my own but failed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so i achieved this using bunch of if-else codes which i am sharing below.
Inintially i set flag to 0, and when logged user tries to open the app then flag is set to 1

```
 public void getCurrentUserInfo() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {

            for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
                String providerId = profile.getProviderId();
                String uid = profile.getUid();
                name = profile.getDisplayName();
                if (flag!=1) {
                    photoUrl = profile.getPhotoUrl();
                    if (photoUrl == null) {
                        Picasso.get()
                                .load(R.drawable.usericon)
                                .resize(6000, 2000)
                                .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
                                .centerInside()
                                .into(mPic);

                    } else {
                        Picasso.get()
                                .load(photoUrl.toString())
                                .resize(6000, 2000)
                                .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
                                .centerInside()
                                .into(mPic);

                    }
                }else{
                    DatabaseReference valueRef = myRef.child("Users").child(name);
                    valueRef.child("ProfileUrl").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            String url = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                            photoUrl=  Uri.parse( url );
                            if (photoUrl == null) {
                                Picasso.get()
                                        .load(R.drawable.usericon)
                                        .resize(6000, 2000)
                                        .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
                                        .centerInside()
                                        .into(mPic);

                            } else {
                                Picasso.get()
                                        .load(photoUrl.toString())
                                        .resize(6000, 2000)
                                        .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
                                        .centerInside()
                                        .into(mPic);

                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
                emailname = profile.getEmail();
                mName.setText(name);
                mEmail.setText(emailname);
                if (name != null && emailname != null) {
                    myRef.child("Users").child(name).child("Email").setValue(emailname);
                    myRef.child("Users").child(name).child("UserId").setValue(uid);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have posted full code in my question this is just the edited part required to initiate my query. For any queries comment.